# Magento 2: How to add Additional Options in cart on "sales_quote_remove_item" event observer

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, additional-options

> I want to add additional options to the next product on the
>   **`sales_quote_remove_item`** event while removing the first product from a cart.

**First Product,** I have already added the first product to cart with additional options

**Second Product** with no additional options(Normal Add to cart).

**While removing First Product** with additional options, I want to check if First product has additional options or not

> **if Yes,** First Product will be removed from the cart, I want to add additional options to the Second Product in the cart as shown in the below
>   screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

> **app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_remove_item">
        <observer name="remove_item" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddFeeToRemoveItemObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\AddFeeToRemoveItemObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json as JsonSerializer;

class AddFeeToRemoveItemObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
    * Json Serializer
    *
    * @var JsonSerializer
    */
    protected $jsonSerializer;

    /**
     * Set payment fee to order
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonSerializer $jsonSerializer,
        RequestInterface $request,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $itemRepository
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
        $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->itemRepository = $itemRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("==============>");

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();

        $additionalOptions = [];
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_delete') {
            if (count($quote->getAllVisibleItems())) {
                foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $loop_item) {
                    $helper = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration');
                    $options=$helper->getCustomOptions($loop_item);
                    $quoteItemFeelabel = "";
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        $quoteItemFeelabel = $option['label'];
                    }
                    $price = 10;
                    $additionalOptions[] = array(
                                'label' => __("My Custom Label"),
                                'value' => $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false),
                            );
                    $loop_item->setProductOption(
                        'additional_options',
                        $this->jsonSerializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I've tried the above code but It's not working.

**If anyone has a solution, please let me know.**

Comment: Do you need the additional options for only one item in the cart or multiple products will have the additional options.

Comment: @RiddhishBhayani Only one

Answer (score 0):

@MohitRane

I would recommend to use it at the quote level rather than Item level. Using that approach it will be easier to achieve that. Quote attribute is the better approach  for ideas you can refer below.

[custom-attributes-to-magento-2-quote-orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277240/how-to-adding-custom-attributes-to-magento-2-quotes-and-orders)